# for x in self.array - strange behavior

Tags: python, arrays, class

Running the following code causes some strange behavior in python 2.7 and 3.5:

```
class Test():
    def __init__(self):
        self.arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
    def worker(self):
        for x in self.arr:
            print (self.arr.pop(0))

b = Test()
b.worker()
```

Will cause the following output

```
>>> b.worker()
1
2
3
>>> b.worker()
4
5
>>> b.worker()
6
```

While the following code sample works as expected, printing the whole array in one go:

```
class Test():
    def __init__(self):
        self.arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
    def worker(self):
        for x in range(len(self.arr)):
            print (self.arr.pop(0))

b = Test()
b.worker()

>>> b.worker()
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

What is going on here, why doesn't the first code sample print and reduce (pop) the whole array when the worker() is called?

Comment: You shouldn't remove from a list while iterating it. You're messing with the iterator in the first.

Comment: @Carcigenicate That's the final answer in my opinion

Comment: Your question is wrong on many levels, but I must say its quite interesting how the iterator behaves while iterating a list which you pop in the same time

Comment: thanks for the duplicate link, "while" seems to be a correct option there.